# What layer should Windsor installers sit in?

Tags: windows-installer, castle-windsor

When using Windsor Installers we have always treated them like config, in that the top level application is in charge of them, allowing the calling app to set its own lifestyles ect.

I am starting to doubt this was the correct approach, for example we have a domain DLL which is used by many applications, this mean we have to repeat the same installers in every application that uses the domain, and update all the apps when new dependencies are added.

Where should our installers reside? Should the domain be self registering? Are we making best use of Winsor?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WindsorInstaller per project, so that all your project specific registration and configuration is encapsulated within rather than up to the projects using the assembly.

The dependent assembly then only needs to pass in the installer when initializing the container.

Answer (score 0):

installers are application level bootstrapping and therefore should live in the application root.

There are several advantages of that, which I won't go into details of.

The more important one is this:

> Even if your multiple applications will end up with installer for a
>   given set of components being exactly the same... so what?

This is **incidental**, and trying to *"optimise"* it by reusing the couple of lines of code of the installer is IMO being penny wise.

What you gain instead, by making your installers application specific is the flexibility to easily change them, and as application matures often you'll find you need to tweak the installer, to account for specific needs of your application.

hope that helps